# How to deploy angular 2 cli app

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am confused on how to host the app. I made it with the cli. DO I just take the dist folder and push it to my hosting service (go daddy)?
What are the steps? I cannot find the steps that I need to upload my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
1- ng build --prod
2- Copy dist 
3- Upload to your web server
4- Point your webserver to dist/index.html
```

Comment: Thank you, this was a big help

Answer (score 1):

npm install --global surge

*# cd to dist folder and, just run…*

$ surge

```
Surge - surge.sh

email: youremail@gmail.com

token: ***************** 
(first time it will ask for password, make sure you have a account on surge.sh)

project path: I:\Code\myangular2app\dist\

size: 33 files, 11.0 MB

domain: auto-generated.surge.sh 
*(delete auto-generated name and put a unique one)*

upload: [====================] 100%, eta: 0.0s

propagate on CDN: [====================] 100%

plan: Free

users: youremail@gmail.com

IP Address: 45.55.110.124

Success! Project is published and running at unique-name.surge.sh
```